# Curvature of a parametric curve in three-dimensional space

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Given a parametric curve
$$x=t\cos t, y=t\sin t, z=at$$
I try to calculate the curvature by using http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Curvature&section=8#Local_expressions_2
I checked the calculations in WolframAlpha and everythings is ok.
I get something like $$\frac{\sqrt{t^4 + 4t^2 + 4 + t^2 a^2 + 4 a^2}}{(t^2 + 2 + a^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$   I found this exercise in two books and they say the result is $$\frac{2}{1+a^2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What books? The curve is a helix whose radius increases over time... obviously this curve can't have constant curvature.

Your denominator should be $(t^2+1+a^2)^{3/2}$, but otherwise your answer matches mine.

Comment: yes, you're right.